# Child Process in Background Issues for Handmade Shell

Tags: c, shell, exec, fork

I'm having a bit of trouble implementing my own handmade shell. I've been able to fork a process and run it in the foregroud with waitpid, but when I try and run simple processes in the background such as 'sleep 5 &', the process seems to run forever. checkListJobs will determine if the process is done running, but it never stops. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I assume the error is in my "foo" function.

```
void insertJob(int pid) {
    printf("beginning job %d.\n", pid);
    struct job *node = malloc(sizeof(struct job));
    node->pid = pid;
    node->next = NULL;

    if(root == NULL) {
        root = node;
    } else {
        node->next = root;
        root = node;
    }
}    

void checkListJobs(int z) {
    curr = root;
    while(curr!=NULL) {
        if(kill(curr->pid,0) != 0)   {
            if(prev==NULL) {
                prev = curr;
                root = curr;
            } else {
                prev->next = curr->next;
            }
        } else {
            if(!z) printf("%d is still running.\n", curr->pid);
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}   


//code for child forking
void foo(char *cmd, char *argv[], int args) {
    int bgFlag;

    if(!strcmp(argv[args], "&")){
        argv[args] = '\0';
        bgFlag = 1;
    }

    int pid = fork();
    int status = 0;

    if(pid==0){
        if(bgFlag) {
            fclose(stdin); // close child's stdin
            fopen("/dev/null", "r"); // open a new stdin that is always empty
        }
        execvp(cmd, argv);
        // this should never be reached, unless there is an error
            fprintf (stderr, "unknown command: %s\n", cmd);
            exit(0);
    } else {
        if(!bgFlag) {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        } else {
            insertJob(pid);
        }
        if (status != 0) {
            fprintf  (stderr, "error: %s exited with status code %d\n", cmd,     status);
        } else {
            // cmd exec'd successfully
        }
    }

    // this is the parent still, since the child always terminates from exec or exit

    // continue being a shell...
}
```

Comment: did you tried to debug program with debugger i.e GDB http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/ or usoing VS?

Comment: @JerryCoffin removed. sorry!

Comment: @RyanSchulze: No problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install a signal handler for SIGCHLD, as that will tell your program when the child process has finished.  Upon receiving SIGCHLD, you should then call wait() (or waitpid() with a PID value of -1, since you won't know which child finished, just that *a* child has finished).

The safest way to write a handler is:

```
volatile sig_atomic_t sigchld;
int handle_child(int sig)
{
  if (sig == SIGCHLD)
    sigchld = 1;
}
```

And in your main loop, check to see if `sigchld` is 1.  If it is, a child process ended, and you can then call `waidpid()` (use a PID of -1, since you won't know which child ended) in a loop (see below) because multiple children might end at the same time.  Also, if any system call return an error and `errno` is `EINTR` then it was interrupted by a signal, so either return to the top of your main loop, or check `sigchld` and handle accordingly (and don't forget to reset `sigchld` back to 0 as quickly as possible).

```
for(;;)
{
  int status;
  pid_t child;

  child = waitpid(-1,&status,WNOHANG);
  if (child == -1) 
  {
    if (errno == ECHILD) break; /* no more children */
    /* error, handle how you wish */
  }
  /* handle the return status of the child */
}
sigchld = 0;
```

You *can* call `waitpid()` from within the signal handler (POSIX says it's safe to do so) but you really shouldn't do *anything else* in the signal handler as it could lead to very subtle bugs (say, SIGCHLD is raised during a call to `malloc()`---any code in the signal handler that results in a call to `malloc()` will lead to *very nasty problems*.  That's why I suggested setting a flag in the signal handler---the less you do in a signal handler, the better).

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I actually solved the problem a different way. I added a pointer to the location of the status for each child process node in the linked list, and called `waitpid(curr->pid,curr->status,WNOHANG);` as the first line in my while loop inside checkListJobs.